# UISearchBar and Two buttons in the Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift4

I am trying to add two buttons and a SearchBar to my navigation controller but the alignment is not correct. I have tried almost everything such as changing the size of SearchBar, UIButton or changing the Y positioning but it didn't work. Any idea how to fix this issue? 
[image]
I am using iOS 11 and Xcode 9

```
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController?.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 30)
    searchController?.delegate = self
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self

    let refineButton = UIButton.init(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    refineButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    refineButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "settings-button"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    refineButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    refineButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true


    let refineItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: refineButton)


    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refineItem
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar
    searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but why not use `navigationItem.searchController = searchController` instead of `navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar`. Of course that only works with iOS 11.

Comment: @rmaddy unfortunately that wouldn't work as the search controller will go below the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    searchController?.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 30)
    searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
}
```